# newcommand in math mode error

Tags: math-mode, macros

I am making a presentation and I need to use the 
following expression quite a lot, so I made the following new command

```
\newcommand{\extreig}[1][\lambda]{\ensuremath{{#1}_{\mbox{{\footnotesize extr}}}(\omega)}}
```

So when I use the command `$\extreig{\mu}$`, I expect to get `$\mu_{\mbox{{\footnotesize extr}}}(\omega)$` (why is on the forum not a latex-editor?), the strange thing is that I get `$\lambda_{\mbox{{\footnotesize extr}}\mu$`.

If I instead use the command `\newcommand` without a default parameter, so `\newcommand{\extreig}[1]{\ensuremath{{#1}_{\mbox{{\footnotesize extr}}}(\omega)}}` then I shows it correctly.

How is this possible?

Comment: You have specified that `\extreig` takes an _optional_ argument so should write `\extreigh[\mu]` with square brackets.

Comment: rather than `_{\mbox{{\footnotesize extr}}` it would be better to use `_{\mathrm{extr}}` and then sizing is automatic, even if the expression appears in a subscript